# WordPress Page comes empty :

Tags: php, wordpress

i have a wordpress landing page for what i dont to use any header/ footer.

I have created a template called **template_landingpage.php** like below

```
<?php 
/*
    Template Name: landingpage
*/
```

now im my page i have selected landingpage as template. Problem is while adding content to page does not show anything and page remains blank. Please advise

Comment: Is that all you have in your template?

Comment: yes i tried adding below as well  if ( have_posts() ) :
                                while ( have_posts() ) :
                                    the_post();
                                    ?>
                                  
                                    <?php
                                endwhile;
                            endif; actually i need an empty template for my page,

Comment: Well, if you don't actually _output_ anything, why would you expect anything other than an empty page? When creating a template, it's up to _you_ to output everything you need.

Comment: i used this template as my template in a wordpress page and i have html in that wp page , should it not be displayed?

Comment: i am not sure if i am using html in page and this is selected as template how should i show data on page

Comment: You should start by looking at any of the thousands guides you can find online about creating custom templates in WP. Basically, when you create a custom template, it's _your_ responsibility to output what you want, where you want it. That's the whole point of custom templates. However, if you _don't_ output anything anywhere, nothing will be outputted(!). WP can't possibly know what you want to do unless you tell it, using code.

Answer (score 0):

You must add `get_header()` and `get_footer()` for any page or add custom header and footer

and i see you are not add any code ,,

you must add while loop to get content from back-end (`wp-admin`)

Answer (score 0):

First try to add get_header() and get_footer() then take a look. The page will be

Comment: That won't output the page contents, though.

Comment: what is your page content?.  Does it come from admin panel is that only static?
Also, you can add that content in front-page.php and try.

Comment: so with an empty header and footer if i just add page content should i use below loop to fetch page contents if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> <?php endwhile;

Comment: No, because for this loop you need to add the dependencies. Which is available in the header part.

Comment: @SureshKumar - _"you can add that content in front-page.php"_ - The OP is creating a _custom_ template so that won't have anything to do with `front-page.php`.

Comment: @Sikander Otherwise try to add wp_head() part in the top of your template and add wp_footer() at bottom of the template and take a look. May it will work for you.

Comment: so what should i do i m not getting it tried to google it says pagename-header.php and pagename-footer.php , get both and add content, but how do i show empty for both and then add content in my page

Comment: @Sikander If you have your site link then please provide where you get the blank page so. I can take a look for your issue.